# Using non-static Combobox vaules on another class in Java

Tags: java, swing, static, instance, non-static

MainWindows.java

```
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void initComponents() {......}

private void GetSqlButonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String[] args1={"1"};
            SqlQuery.main(args1);
        }
    }); 
    } 

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Look and feel setting code created by Netbeans
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

private javax.swing.JComboBox ComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JButton GetSqlButon;
}
```

SqlQuery.java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SqlQuery {

   static String Query = "select top 10 date,number from Records\n" +
    "where date between '2014-01-01 10:00:00.000' and '2014-01-01 11:00:00.000'\n" +
    "and ID='013'";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.100;user=sa;password=passsa;database=ExampleDB");
          Statement sta = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Query);
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
          int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
           while (rs.next()) {
             for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
              if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
              String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
              System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
             }
        System.out.println("");
             }
          con.close();
          } 

        catch (Exception e)
           {
           System.out.println("Baglanti Hatasi");
           }   

    }


}
```

When i Jbutton i can retrieve resultset from SqlQuery.java succesfully.

I have problem about Combobox. I want; when pressing Jbutton for get resultset from SqlQuery.java Combobox selected value must using in SqlQuery.java for this line "and ID='comboboxvalue'";

How can i send this non-static value to static method of SqlQuery.java?

I know i must create instance but i dont know how. Could you please someone explain it?

Comment: 1) You don't need or even want two `main` methods. 2) Don't explicitly call the `main` method. 3) Also just create an instance of `SQLQuery` and have a method that returns some value that you can use in your combobox. 4) Another suggestion is to learn to hand code Swing GUI before jumping into GUI Builder. See [Creating GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment, you don't need two `main` methods. Instead just create an instance of `SqlQuery` and have a constructor that will pass be passed a value. Something like this

```
public class SqlQuery {

    String comboBoxValue;

    public SqlQuery(String value) {
        comboBoxValue = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can just pass the value. to the constructor

```
String value = (String)comboBox.getSelectItem();
SqlQuery sql = new SqlQuery(value);
```

Also it looks like the the query should return a result, so you *want* to just have a `ResultSet` return from a static method, that you can use in your GUI class. Something like

```
public class SqlQuery {
    public static ResultSet sendQuery(String value) {

    }
}
```

Then you can just do this

```
String value = (String)comboBox.getSelectItem();
ResultSet rs = SqlQuery.setQuery(value);
// do something with result set.
```

There are a number of ways you can approach this.

Also note, you should be using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to avoid SQL injection.